# php, mysql join table columns with another table rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have issue getting results from two database table. here is what i have:

```
table A: 'courses' 

math  | history  | geography  | computer 
1     | 2        | 3          | 4
```

and Table B

```
user_id | classroom_id | course 
1       | 5            | 3
1       | 5            | 4
1       | 6            | 2
```

I returned the table A on a for each loop but I would like to check what courses the user 1 has to return true or false on any Table a columns.
Any help appreciated. 
**I need help not negative votes :(**

Comment: Did you really create the columns for every subject in `table A`?

Comment: If it's not too late to restructure your tables, I would really suggest re-thinking your `courses` table to be two columns, `course_id` and `course_name`.

Comment: Not for every columns, for example user 1 has only 2 and I just create 2 rows on table B

Comment: 'not too late' In fact, it's too early to answer until you do.

Comment: No no, I am talking about `table A`. `Table B` is fine.

Comment: I think that table structure is a bit wrong... Do you have a separate column for each course? What for? It should be a row for each course, and than it could be simply joined as OneToMany.

Comment: Don't worry about down votes, just communicate and you'll get your solution.

Comment: @TylerRoper It is never too late.

Comment: I actually created like this to be able to add more courses in future and not editing the whole columns.

Comment: No, you're totally wrong here. You should structure your table like you don't have to modify it. In this way you'll have to modify the `table schema` to add a new course. You add rows, not columns.

Comment: You are right @Shaharyar, i'm going to change it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your database set up wrong I believe. What you want is something like

```
Table_A:
PKEY |    Course

1    |    Math
2    |    History
3    |    Geography
4    |    Computer



Table_B:
user_id | classroom_id | course 
1       | 5            | 3
1       | 5            | 4
1       | 6            | 2
```

Then you could do something like

```
SELECT 
TableA.PKEY,
TableA.Course,
TableB.user_id,
TableB.classroom_id,
TableB.course,
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.PKEY = TableB.course
```

^^This will return the data from BOTH tables.

you see this line

```
ON TableA.PKEY = TableB.course

                    ^^This is called the foreign key.
```

BIG GOTCHA: Make SURE that the columns for both of those ^^^ are set up EXACTLY the same. For instance, IF TableA.PKEY is an UNSIGNED INT(10), then TableB.course MUST also be UNSIGNED INT(10). They have to be identical for the join to work correctly.

Comment: I think you are right man, let me try it. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Anytime. I had some trouble with SQL when I first started. Still do as a matter of fact... XD

Comment: Ditto: Had a hell of a time breaking the mentality that "database = spreadsheet". Start thinking of DBs as data sets, and queries are just set operations.